# Any equivalent gulp plugin for doing "grunt bower"?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, bower, gulp

With `grunt`, I could use command `grunt bower` (provided by [`grunt-bower-requirejs`](https://github.com/ck86/gulp-bower-files)) to auto-generate `RequireJS` config file for my local `bower` components.

Is there any plugin for [`gulp`](http://gulpjs.com) to perform similar task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mind that bowerRequireJS is an asynchronous function. So you would need to use a callback (or synchronously return a Promise) to mark that task as asynchronous like so:

```
gulp.task('bower', function(callback) {
    var options = {
        baseUrl: 'src',
        config: 'src/app/require.config.js',
        transitive: true
    };

    bowerRequireJS(options, function (rjsConfigFromBower) {
        callback();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but what exactly is the `baseUrl` and what is the path specified under `config`?

Comment: Bower describes `baseUrl` as the "Path which all dependencies will be relative to". the `config` path points to your JS file that includes as `requirejs.config()` declaration.

Answer (score 14):

**UPDATE: for future readers, please look at the correct answer from @user2326971**

Solved it by hook up `gulp` directly with node module `bower-requirejs`

```
npm install bower-requirejs --save-dev
```

In `gulpfile.js`

```
var bowerRequireJS = require('bower-requirejs');

gulp.task('bower', function() {
    var options = {
        baseUrl: 'src',
        config: 'src/app/require.config.js',
        transitive: true
    };

    bowerRequireJS(options, function (rjsConfigFromBower) {
        console.log("Updated src/app/require.config.js !");
    });
});
```