# Auto-wire bower dependencies with gulp?

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, bower, gulp, javascript-build

Anyone aware of plugins for gulp that will auto-wire bower dependencies?

I'd like to find plugins that handle both standard script tags, and require.js syntax.

This is exactly like the plugins for grunt:

**grunt-wiredep**

Inject your Bower components right into your HTML using Grunt.

**grunt-bower-requirejs**

Automagically wire-up installed Bower components into your RequireJS config.

(From the bower website: http://bower.io/docs/tools/)

Or if not, any suggestions for the best way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any equivalent gulp plugin for doing "grunt bower"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631744/any-equivalent-gulp-plugin-for-doing-grunt-bower)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep

Directory content automatic dependecies for bower.

Use node command line:

```
require('wiredep')({src:['prueba.html']})
```